# Typescript type not supported by scrypt

Tags: bitcoin-sv

I'm trying to use an array in my smart contract, however I'm getting this error:

> Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite

```
let tokenid: FixedArray<ByteString,1000>;
```

Is it possible to use such type, and if so how should I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a issue.

try to install the latest hotfix version:

```
npm i scrypt-ts@beta
```

after that, you can do this:

```
let tokenid: FixedArray<ByteString,1000> = fill(toByteString(""), 1000);
```